# Why do I get "invalid decimal literal" when pasting an URL into the spotdl function?

Tags: python, spotify

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/spotDL/spotify-downloader) for downloading Spotify songs.

However, I get the following error:

```
pip install spotdl
```

```
spotdl download https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1E8UXBoz02kGID

 Cell In[3], line 1
    spotdl download https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1E8UXBoz02kGID
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

Is there a problem with my function?
This error usually occurs with mathematical functions but my code seems pretty basic.
Not sure what I did wrong here

Comment: What you did wrong is try to run a console script in python.

Comment: Python reports both *lexical* errors and *parsing* errors as syntax errors, but the lexical error (invalid integer literal "37i9...") is discovered and reported before an yparsing error (such as an identifier "spotdl" followed immediately by another identifier "download").